# VBA to automatically update a table in one workbook based on a sheet in a different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Good Afternoon Everyone,

I have two workbooks where i want Excel to automatically update the table in one sheet based on the other one.
i want the table in workbook MergetestSheet!2015 to automatically update based on the table in workbook 2015Sheet!1 Range A1:p144,031. Can someone help with the VBA code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Devin's answer works well but you want to try to avoid using `.select` when at all possible. I would suggest something more along the lines of:

```
sub Transfer()

    Dim copyRangeValues as Long
    Dim destinationRange as Range
    Workbook("2015.xls").Activate
    set copyRangeValues = Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1:P144031").Value
    Worksheet("Mergetest.xls").Activate
    set destinationRange = Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1:P144031") 
    destinationRange.Value = copyRangeValues

End Sub
```

This assumes that A1:P144031 is also the range of cells that your table in the second sheet is in. You would need to modify that if its not, or add some counter variables to make it more automated.

Answer (score -1):

You could always just copy the data from one workbook and paste it to the other.

Something like this:

```
Sub Transfer_Data()

Windows("2015").Activate
Range ("A1:P144031").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Mergetest").Activate
Range ("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```